# Importing file script works but does not put the mesh in the work space

Tags: mesh, scripting, add-on, import

I am trying to write a code as part of a larger add on, and one component is to have a button that will open the file explorer and import .stl or .off files. My code is reading the data but I cannot get the imported mesh to show in my work space (as an object I can then modify). I want this function to be as if I went to file--import--.stl (where it shows up in my 3D work space). I am new to blender and python (double-whammy) so any help is appreciated!

EDIT: I have reuploaded the code. I know it is reading the file without spitting out any errors but I don't know what to change/add to get it to import as a mesh in my 3D work space.

EDIT 2: I have posted my most recent code and I still not getting any error messages in the terminal but the file I am trying to import is no where to be seen in the work space.

```
import bpy
from bpy_extras.io_utils import ImportHelper
from bpy.types import Operator
from bpy.props import StringProperty, BoolProperty, EnumProperty

import base64


def read_some_data(context, filepath):
    #print("running read_some_data...")
    f = open(filepath, 'rb')
    data = f.read()
    encoded = base64.b64encode(data)
    data = encoded
    f.close()



    return {'FINISHED'}

class stl_file_import(Operator,ImportHelper):
    bl_idname = "object2surf.invoke_import"
    bl_label = "Import Mesh"
    bl_description = "Import triangular surfaces in .json,.jmsh,.bmsh,.off,.medit,.stl,.smf,.gts"
   
   

    # ImportHelper mixin class uses this
    filename_ext = "*.json;*.jmsh;*.bmsh;*.off;*.medit;*.stl;*.smf;*.gts"

    filter_glob: StringProperty(
        default="*.json;*.jmsh;*.bmsh;*.off;*.medit;*.stl;*.smf;*.gts",
        options={'HIDDEN'},
        maxlen=2048,  # Max internal buffer length, longer would be clamped.
    )


    use_setting: BoolProperty(
        name="Example Boolean",
        description="Example Tooltip",
        default=True,
    )



    def execute(self, context):
        return read_some_data(context, self.filepath)
    def add_mesh_to_scene(scene, mesh):
        obj = bpy.ops.import_scene.obj(filepath=path, axis_forward='-Z', axis_up='Y', filter_glob="*.obj;*.stl")
        scene.objects.link(obj)
        return obj

###
def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(stl_file_import)
    bpy.types.TOPBAR_MT_file_import.append(menu_func_import)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(stl_file_import)
    bpy.types.TOPBAR_MT_file_import.remove(menu_func_import)
```

Comment: Hello. It seems you have some unused code here, so it's a bit hard to understand what you're trying to do. Could you clean the script a little bit ?

Comment: Your code only reads the file, it doesn’t convert it from stl/off to blender data nor adds any new objects to the scene

Comment: I have reuploaded the code and tried to clean it up the best I can. I can tell it is reading the file but I do not know how to get it to import as an object into my workspace. There are no errors being printed out either.

Comment: try: `bpy.ops.import_scene.obj(filepath=self.filepath, ...)` to pass selected path from ImportHelper to SceneImporter

Comment: @relaxed I have that line in the code but it isnt doing anything. I tried changing .obj to .stl or .off and blender crashed with no error message in the command terminal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, also with last change I see `filepath=path` not `filepath=self.filepath` in your example. And the import operator was moved in a function that´s not called. I'm beginning to think there might be some general confusion about importing objects into Blender. No need to open or read a file (function 'read_some_data'). No need to link imported objects to Scene by yourself (scene.objects.link). Imported objects are linked to the active collection by default. It´s all done by the Import-Operators. Let's break down the stuff.

**Direct import:**

```
import bpy
bpy.ops.import_mesh.stl()
```

raises error `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: ''` because invalid (empty) filepath was passed to operator.

```
import bpy
my_filepath = r"C:\Users\username\Documents\untitled.stl" # (Windows example: r(String) to format windows pathes)
bpy.ops.import_mesh.stl(filepath = my_filepath)
```

object was imported and linked to active collection as long as `filepath` is valid. This means there must be a file named 'untitled.stl' in the given directory. `filepath` needs to be the complete path from mount to file-extension.

**Direct import with selection:**

```
import bpy
bpy.ops.import_mesh.stl('INVOKE_DEFAULT')
```

If ImportOperator is called with execution context 'INVOKE_DEFAULT' behind the scene another operator opens for file + folder selection (user interaction). By clicking the execution button, user `filepath` (selection) is passed to the ImportOperator. Rest as before. Object is imported and linked to active collection.

**Import with selection from Panel:**

Here the operator call is some different because Panel is invoked by default and `layout.operator` needs the bl_idname of the ImportOperator.

```
import bpy

# UI                      
class TEST_PT_Panel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_idname = 'TEST_PT_Panel'
    bl_label = "Test Panel"                      
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
    bl_category = "TEST"
    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        layout.operator('import_mesh.stl',  text="import .stl")  # use operator.bl_idname (all behind 'bpy.ops.') without 'INVOKE_DEFAULT'
        layout.operator('import_scene.obj', text="import .obj")  # .obj importer example
        
# REGISTER
bpy.utils.register_class(TEST_PT_Panel)
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining!